# Does new int[] return the address of the first element in the array or the address of the entire array?

Tags: c++

```
int *a = new int[16];
```

How do I access the array afterwards?

Does `a` hold the address of the entire array or just the first element in the array?

Basically, I have this code,

```
struct student {
   string name;
   int age;
};

int num_students = get_number_of_students();
struct student *students = new student[num_students];
```

Now, how do I access the elements in that array?

Comment: The first element - access the elements using a[some_index] - and do yourself a favour: use std::vector instead.

Comment: As an aside, in C++, you do not need to repeat the word `struct` when making a `student` object.

Comment: Also in C++, use `std::vector` for dynamically sized arrays.

Comment: The address of the whole array and the address of the first element have the same value. So the answer is both. As for access, just access like you would be a regular array, because (shock) when you access an array, the array is converted into a pointer, so you have been using pointers all  along without realising it.

Comment: @john that should be posted as an answer instead

Comment: @ChrisMM I see, I only have rudimentary C programming knowledge.

Comment: From that comment, it's worth pointing out that C and C++ are _distinct_ programming  languages.

Comment: @Isn't C++ supposed to be a superset of C?

Comment: Originally? Sure. But that was ever such a long time ago.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`a` is simply a pointer to an `int`. It points to the beginning of the block of memory you have allocated. It does not carry any information about the size of the array.

As advised in comments, best practice in C++ is to use a `std::vector` for this, letting it handle the memory allocation (and importantly *de-allocation*) and provide convenient functions (via STL) for determining size and iterating over its elements.

```
std::vector<student> students(num_students);
```

---

*Small additional note:* In C++ structs do not require that they be prepended with `struct` on using them to declare a variable.

```
struct student *students = new student[num_students];
```

May simply be:

```
student *students = new student[num_students];
```

Comment: Well put. Answers the question as asked *and then* suggests best practices.